# list tables in redshift using SQLWorkbench

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

How do I list tables in redshift ?

I am using SQLWorkbench.

I tried `SHOW TABLES;` and `\dt` are not recognized commands.

Any help?

Comment: SQL Workbench also has the `WbList` command: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-list

Comment: I tried WbList, it didn't give me anything useful. Has this changed in the last ~1.5 years?

Comment: @szeitlin "didn't give anything useful" isn't a usable problem description

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to get the list of tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT tablename
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
ORDER BY tablename;
```

More info here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG_examples.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Responding to comments a year later is not helpful, either. My guess is that what I meant was, "This returned no results." But I don't remember. Because it was a year ago.

Answer (score 8):

On Sql workbench,

Go to Tools -> New DBexplorerWindow

it will load all the tables and click on table name shown the table schema as well

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
select datname, nspname, relname, sum(rows) as rows
from pg_class, pg_namespace, pg_database, stv_tbl_perm
where pg_namespace.oid = relnamespace
and pg_class.oid = stv_tbl_perm.id
and pg_database.oid = stv_tbl_perm.db_id
and datname = '**db_name**' and nspname = '**schema_name**'
group by datname, nspname, relname
order by datname, nspname, relname;
```